# Error Updating Roles

Tags: php, codeigniter, bonfire

I have an issue with one of my projects, as soon as I try to update a role I got the following error.

> The value in "Role Name" is already being used.

When I am editing/updating the role, the role name shouldn't be validated. Why is this happening?

I've looked into the controller and the model code and it just uses the regular code.

Controller:

```
if ($type == 'insert') {
    $id = $this->role_model->insert($data);
    $return = is_numeric($id);
} elseif ($type == 'update') {
    $return = $this->role_model->update($id, $data);
}
```

Model:

```
public function update($id = null, $data = null)
{
    // If this role is set to default, then set all others to NOT be default.
    if (isset($data['default']) && $data['default'] == 1) {
        $this->db->set('default', 0)
                 ->update($this->table_name);
    }

    return parent::update($id, $data);
}
```

Comment: Your error says "Role Name Already Used". Use another one.

Comment: Thanks, But I'm editing/updating the role, the role name shouldn't be validated.

Comment: Then disable validation in those methods. Should look something like `if($this->form_validation->run()...`.

Comment: Now, thanks a lot, this was the problem, it requires it to be unique on update. Weird since the module was created using the bonfire code creation tool. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the validation rules as suggested by Kisaragi

```
protected $updateValidationRules = array(
    array(
        'field' => 'role_name',
        'label' => 'lang:role_name',
        'rules' => 'required|trim|max_length[60]|unique[roles.role_name,roles.role_id]',
    ),
);
```

to

```
protected $updateValidationRules = array(
    array(
        'field' => 'role_name',
        'label' => 'lang:role_name',
        'rules' => 'required|trim|max_length[60]|',
    ),
);
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ensure columns role_name and role_id have unique constraint to avoid possibility of updating to something already exists.